# How can I prove that $\ln z=\ln|z|+i\arg(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> How to prove:
> $$\ln z = \ln|z| + i \arg z$$

How to prove this equation? Maybe  this is an easy question.Please don't give this question a down arrow as for I am a new man in complex analysis.I need your help.

Comment: What is your definition of $\ln z$? Also, write $z = r e^{iθ}$ – what is $r$ and what is $θ$?

Comment: Please make an effort to use less inane titles. "How to do this? This is easy" is not going to help anyone who has the same question to find your question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't type formula in the tittle,so I have to ues inane titles.Could you teach me how to type a formula as the title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let  $$z=re^{i\theta}$$
$$|z|=|re^{i\theta}|=|r|\cdot|e^{i\theta}|=r$$
$$\implies \ln(z)=\ln(r)+\ln(e^{i\theta})=\ln|z|+i\theta=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{arg}(z)$$

Comment: With the argument defined up to some multiple of $\,2\pi\,$ ...

Answer (score 4):

A standard definition of complex logarithm is:

> Complex logarithm of $z$ denoted by $\ln{z}$ is the complex number $a$
>   that satisfies $e^a=z$ or it's the inverse of the function $e^z$

By Euler's formula we know that any complex number $z$ can be represented as $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ where $|z|$ represents it's modulus (distance of the complex number $z$ from the origin) and $\theta$ is the argument ( the angle the line joining $z$ and origin makes with the real axis).

Now, for the sake of the $z$ having a unique representation as $e^a$ we need to make the argument of  $z$ is unique. How can this be done?. We can restrict the argument $\theta$ to the interval $\left(-\pi,\pi\right]$. And we call this argument as 'principal argument'.

With the knowledge aquired from the above paragraphs $$z=|z|e^{i\theta}=e^{\ln{|z|}}\cdot {e^{i\theta}}$$
$$z=e^{\ln{z}+i\theta}$$
$$\Rightarrow \ln{z}=\ln{|z|}+i\theta$$
or
$$\Rightarrow \ln{z}=\ln{|z|}+i\arg{z}$$
Where $\arg{z}$ is the principal argument.

But, actually complex logarithm is a multivariate function . 
$$\Rightarrow \ln{z}=\ln{|z|}+i\left(\arg{z}+2n\pi\right) \space \quad n\in \mathbb{I}$$
.The proof of the above is similar without the existence of the condition $\theta$ is restricted.

Answer (score 2):

You start by writing the complex number $z$ in polar form: $z = r\!\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}$, where $r$ is the modulus of $z$ and $\theta$ is the argument of $z$. Then use the law that $\ln  (ab) = \ln a + \ln b$.
\begin{array}{ccc}
z &=& r\!\operatorname{e}^{i\theta} \\
\ln z &=& \ln\left(r\!\operatorname{e}^{i\theta}\right) \\
&=& \ln r + \ln \left(\operatorname{e}^{i\theta} \right) \\
&=& \ln r + i\theta
\end{array}

Since $r = |z|$ and $\theta = \arg z$ we have $\ln z = \ln|z| + i \arg z$. Obviously, $\theta$ is only well-defined up to multiples of $2\pi$. For example, $\arg 1 = \ldots,-2\pi,0,2\pi,\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what happens when you evaluate
$$
e^{\ln z}
$$
and
$$
e^{\ln |z|+i\arg z}
$$